# Core Data How would I use core data to keep the user logged in?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am making this app called imagur and it has a signup and login and whenever I leave the app when the user already has an account I want it to automatically recognize the user how would I do that this is what I have so far :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var signupActive = true

    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    func displayAlert(title:String, error:String) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    @IBOutlet var username: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var password: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet var alreadyRegistered: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var signUpButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var signUpLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var signUpToggleButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func toggleSignUp(sender: AnyObject) {

        if signupActive == true {

            signupActive = false

            signUpLabel.text = "Use the form below to log in"

            signUpButton.setTitle("Log In", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            alreadyRegistered.text = "Not Registered?"

            signUpToggleButton.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        } else {

            signupActive = true

            signUpLabel.text = "Use the form below to sign up"

            signUpButton.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            alreadyRegistered.text = "Already Registered?"

            signUpToggleButton.setTitle("Log In", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        }


    }

    @IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

        var error = ""

        if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

            error = "Please enter a username and password"

        }


        if error != "" {

            displayAlert("Error In Form", error: error)

        } else {



            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if signupActive == true {

                var user = PFUser()
                user.username = username.text
                user.password = password.text

                user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (succeeded: Bool!, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in

                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if signupError == nil  {
                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.

                        println("signed up")


                    } else {
                        if let errorString = signupError.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {

                            error = errorString

                        } else {

                            error = "Please try again later."

                        }

                        self.displayAlert("Could Not Sign Up", error: error)

                    }
                }

            } else {

                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text, password:password.text) {
                    (user: PFUser!, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in


                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if signupError == nil {

                        println("logged in")

                    } else {

                        if let errorString = signupError.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {

                            error = errorString

                        } else {

                            error = "Please try again later."

                        }

                        self.displayAlert("Could Not Log In", error: error)


                    }
                }


            }


        }


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }        

}
```

Oh and I am also using Parse.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are wanting to do is remember that a user is logged in across app closures/reboots, then you can simply save that fact with NSUserDefaults and check [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) at launch.  This is a pretty straightforward approach.

Using core data just to persist if a user is logged in is probably overkill.

If you are actually needing to remember their user name and password, then that is another question entirely.  You should **not** user Core Data or NSUserDefaults in this scenario.  To securely store user credentials you'll want to use the [Keychain Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898) in the security framework.

Comment: Actually, for this use case (at least as OP describes it) NSURLCredentialStorage is a better choice than to use the Keychain directly. Always prefer the higher level abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Parse you can do this to make sure the user stays logged in

```
 // Sets default page to Main Feed if user is already logged in
    if PFUser.current() != nil {
        let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let feedNavigationController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedNavigationController")
        
        window?.rootViewController = feedNavigationController
        
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
```